# Getting .net error while installing Github

Tags: windows-7, installation, git, .net-framework

**Github Installation failed with the below error.**

Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64) has failed to install with the following error message: "A failure occurred attempting to install the .NET Framework 4 Full."

The following components failed to install: - Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\NAREND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5C33.tmp\install.log' for more information.

**The log states that some registry is not setting, not getting what is it.**

**Below is the install.log**

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.0.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 4.5', phase BuildList
Looking up path for special folder 'WindowsFolder'
Running check with folder 'C:\Windows\System32' and file 'msi.dll'
Attempting to find file 'C:\Windows\System32\msi.dll'
File version is '5.0.7600.16385'
Setting value '5.0.7600.16385 {version}' for property 'VersionMsiDll'
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 4.5':
Property: [VersionMsiDll] = 5.0.7600.16385 {version}
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '4.5': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22299': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsiDll' and value '4.5.6001.22308': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 4.5' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\NAREND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5C33.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\NAREND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5C33.tmp\"
(28-05-2014 22:36:17) Downloading 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=182805' to 'C:\Users\NAREND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5C33.tmp\'
Download completed at 28-05-2014 22:36:18
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\NAREND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5C33.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\NAREND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5C33.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Installing using command 'C:\Users\NAREND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5C33.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' and parameters ' /q /norestart /ChainingPackage FullX64Bootstrapper /lcid 1033'
Process exited with code 1060
Status of package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

**How to resolve this Issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\REGSVR32.EXE %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\WUAUENG.DLL
```

Running the above command did resolve this issue. Got the Answer from the below Link.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283381/how-to-fix-this-error-while-installing-github-on-windows-7-64bit][1]